# AWS CodeDeploy: Script at specified location: ... "failed to complete in 5 seconds"

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment

I'm using AWS CodeDeploy and getting an error message:

> Script at specified location: ... "failed to complete in 5 seconds"

the script is called from appspec.yml->hooks:->BeforeInstall:

How can I fix it?

Is it an indication of something?
Why is it 5 seconds limit?
How can I increase it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify a timeout for each stage, see **[CodeDeploy — Structure of 'hooks' Section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html#reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks-section-structure)**.

For example to set it to 120 seconds:

```
hooks:
 BeforeInstall:
 - location: /script/location/xyz.sh
   timeout: 120
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I can prove no one was ever complaining about this error message
https://www.google.com/search?num=40&newwindow=1&rlz=1C1AWFC_enAU793AU793&ei=nWATXJjOGsOFwgSDqryYAQ&q=%22failed+to+complete+in%22++%22seconds%22+%22Script+at+specified+location%3A%22&oq=%22failed+to+complete+in%22++%22seconds%22+%22Script+at+specified+location%3A%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30.25650.26972..27378...0.0..0.403.1171.3-2j1......0....1j2..gws-wiz.......0i71.-pUhsiMWOrw